# Errors when using gitlab-ctl uninstall

Tags: uninstall, gitlab

After trying to install gitlab using the .deb package they provide, I gave it up and now I wan't to uninstall it.

But when I run "sudo gitlab-ctl uninstall" it only get:

[image: gitlab uninstall errors]

I have absolutely no idea what I can do know and I hope that reinstalling linux is not the only way...

Answer (score 1):

From the [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/135) in the official site, you can try

1. `gitlab-ctl stop`
2. `gitlab-ctl uninstall`
3. Delete all files/directories
4. Reboot

Comment: There is [a section about uninstall in readme file](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/6-9-stable/README.md#uninstalling-omnibus-gitlab)

Answer (score 1):

**1.gitlab-ctl stop**

Stop the services.

**2.gitlab-ctl cleanse**

Delete *all* gitlab data, and start from scratch.

**3. gitlab-ctl uninstall**

Kill all processes and uninstall the process supervisor (data will be preserved).

**4. remove package.**

// Debian/Ubuntu

sudo dpkg -r gitlab-ce

// Redhat/Centos

sudo rpm -e gitlab-ce

**5. Reboot**

Answer (score 0):

After installing a .deb with dpkg/apt-get/aptitude the best way to remove a packge is to use the same way. Try

`apt-get autoremove --purge PKGNAME`

to remove the package from your system.

Comment: Thats true, but when installing gitlab it wants "gitlab-ctl reconfigure", which does a lot changes, and when you wan't to uninstall it, the docs says that you should run "gitlab-ctl uninstall" and then apt-get remove..